# Using autowired dependencies with certain mock dependency in Spring4

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have a rest resource for signup and login. both in a controller class. the controller class has a dependency to a service class with the business logic. the service class has further dependencies. cause i use an embedded db for testing, i want to use the real dependencies of my app instead to mock them with something like @injectmock @mock. there is only one certain dependency i have to mock. its the dependency for sending emails after a signup process. how to write test cases with @autowired function and one certain mock dependency for email notification?

```java
    @Controller
    public class AccountCommandsController {

        @Autowired
        private LogoutService service;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity login(@RequestBody Account account) {

            AccountLoginEvent accountLoginEvent = service.loginAccount(new RequestAccountLoginEvent(account.getEmailAddress(), account.getPassword()));

            if (accountLoginEvent.isLoginGranted()) {

                return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

            } else {

                return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

            }
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity signup(@RequestBody Account account) {

            AccountSignupEvent signedupEvent = service.signupAccount(new RequestAccountSignupEvent(account.getEmailAddress(), account.getPassword()));

            if (signedupEvent.isSignupSuccess()) {



        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

        } else if (signedupEvent.isDuplicateEmailAddress()) {

            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);

        } else if (signedupEvent.isNoSignupMailSent()) {

            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);

        } else {

            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);

            }
        }
    }
```

```java
    @Service
    public class LogoutService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountsRepository accountsRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;

    @Autowired
    private HashService hashService;

    public AccountSignupEvent signupAccount(RequestAccountSignupEvent signupEvent) {

        if (accountsRepository.existEmailAddress(signupEvent.getEmailAddress())) {
            return AccountSignupEvent.duplicateEmailAddress();
        }

        Account newAccount = new Account();
        newAccount.setCreated(new Date());
        newAccount.setModified(new Date());
        newAccount.setEmailAddress(signupEvent.getEmailAddress());
        newAccount.setPassword(signupEvent.getPassword());
        newAccount.setVerificationHash(hashService.getUniqueVerificationHash());

        SignupMailEvent mailSentEvent = mailService.sendSignupMail(new RequestSignupMailEvent(newAccount));

        if (!mailSentEvent.isMailSent()) {
            return AccountSignupEvent.noMailSent();
        }

        Account persistedAccount = accountsRepository.persist(newAccount);

        return AccountSignupEvent.accountCreated(persistedAccount);
    }

    public AccountLoginEvent loginAccount(RequestAccountLoginEvent loginEvent) {

        if (accountsRepository.existLogin(loginEvent.getEmailAddress(), loginEvent.getPassword())) {
            return AccountLoginEvent.granted();
        }

        return AccountLoginEvent.denied();
        }
    }
```

```java
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
    @Transactional
    @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
    public class LogoutTest {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Autowired
        private AccountCommandsController controller;

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();
        }

        @Test
        public void signupNoMail() throws Exception {
            doReturn(AccountSignupEvent.noMailSent()).when(service).signupAccount(any(RequestAccountSignupEvent.class));
    //        when(controller.service.signupAccount(any(RequestAccountSignupEvent.class))).thenReturn(AccountSignupEvent.noMailSent());
            mockMvc.perform(post("/rest/signup")
                    .content(new Gson().toJson(new Account(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), UUID.randomUUID().toString())))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andExpect(status().isServiceUnavailable());
        }
    }
```

I hope you see the problem. Every dependency works fine instead mailservice. I dont want to use @injectmock and @mock with  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); in my test file, because of the neccessary to provide for all dependencies mocks.

Answer (score 0):

if your dependencies are running and you have a configuration class where you have defined the endpoint, you can use ConfigurableApplicationContext class, something like this:

```
 public class test {

     private static ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext;
     private LogoutService service;

     @AfterClass
     public static void destroy() {
       appContext.close();
     }

     @Before
     public void setup() {             
         appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(YourClassConfig.class);

         service = appContext.getBean(LogoutService.class);        
     }

     @Test
     public void beansAreCreated() {
         assertNotNull(service);        
     }     
 }
```

Or you can re-write your endpoint with a configuration class and you can use WireMock (http://wiremock.org) to emulate your dependency with real data, this should be something like this:

```
 public class test {

     @Rule
     public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(15000);

     private static ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext;
     private LogoutService service;

     private static String serviceMockUrl;

     @AfterClass
     public static void destroy() {
       appContext.close();
     }

     @Before
     public void setup() {
         serviceMockUrl = "http://localhost:" + wireMockRule.port();
         appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestConfig.class);

         stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("urlToRequest")).
            willReturn(aResponse().
                    withStatus(SC_OK).
                    withBody(createJsonArray("MapWithYourData").
                    withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")));

         service = appContext.getBean(LogoutService.class);        
     }

     @Test
     public void beansAreCreated() {
         assertNotNull(service);        
    }       

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {
         @Bean
         public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
             return new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {{
                 setProperties(new Properties() {{
                    setProperty("service.url", serviceMockUrl);
                 }});
             }};
         }
     }     
 }
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is easily implemented using [Spring Profiles](http://diarmuidmoloney.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/spring-environments/).

On way to achieve it is the following:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

   //this is the real mail service
   @Bean
   public MailService mailService() {
      return new MailService(); //or whatever other bean creation logic you are using
   }

   //whatever else

}

@Configuration
@Profile("mockMail")
public class MockMailServiceConfig {

   @Bean
   @Primary
   public MailService mockMailService() {
      return mock(MailService.class);
   }
}
```

Your test class would then look like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@ActiveProfiles("mockMail")
public class LogoutTest {

   //do your testing
}
```

Note the use of `@Primary` in `MockMailServiceConfig`. I opted for this way since it wouldn't require you to introduce profiles anywhere else if you are not already using them. `@Primary` tells spring to use that specific bean if multiple candidates are available (in this case there is the real mail service and the mock service)